# creating dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create a html with dynamic data for specific month.
I want for may month I have

```js
const response=[{
    "UserName": "User1",
    "Type": "type3",
    "month": "May",
    "Week1": 2,
    "Week2": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "Type": "type2",
    "month": "July",
    "Week1": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "Type": "type1",
    "month": "Jun",
    "Week2": 1,
    "Week1": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "Type": "type2",
    "month": "July",
    "Week3": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "Type": "type3",
    "month": "May",
    "Week1": 2,
    "Week2": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "Type": "type1",
    "month": "Jun",
    "Week2": 1,
    "Week1": 1
  }
  
];
$('#geo_summary thead').find('tr').append(
                    Object.keys(response[0]).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
                    );
                    $('#geo_summary tbody').append(
                    response.map(row => $('<tr>').append(
                     Object.values(row).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
                    ))
                    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="geo_summary" class="basic-table"> <thead><tr></tr> </thead> <tbody> </tbody></table>
```

expected as
[image: expected html]

Comment: Sometimes week, sometimes Week? July to Jul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map()` and `reduce()` of `Array.prototype`.

```js
const weeksByMonth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"].map(m => {
    const byMonth = response.filter(x => x.month.substring(0, 3) == m);
    if (byMonth.length)
        return {
            month: m,
            weeks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(w => byMonth.find(x => "Week" + w in x))
        };
}).filter(m => m);
const monthWeeks = weeksByMonth.reduce((w, m) => w.concat(m.weeks.map(w => "Week" + w).concat("Total")), []);
const users = response.reduce((u, x) => {
    if (!(x.UserName in u))
        u[x.UserName] = {};
    const user = u[x.UserName];
    if (!(x.Type in user))
        user[x.Type] = {};
    const {UserName, Type, month, ...weeks} = x;
    user[x.Type][x.month.substring(0, 3)] = weeks;
    return u;
}, {});
$("#geo_summary thead").find("tr")
    .append($("<td>"))
    .append($("<td>"))
    .append(weeksByMonth.map(m => $("<td>").text(m.month).attr("colspan", m.weeks.length + 1).css("text-align", "center")))
    .after($("<tr>")
        .append($("<td>").text(Object.keys(users)[0]))
        .append($("<td>").text("Yearly"))
        .append(monthWeeks.map(w => $("<td>").text(w))));
$("#geo_summary tbody").append(
    Object.keys(users).reduce((r, u, i) => {
        if(i)
            r.push($("<tr>")
                .append($("<td>").text(u))
                .append(monthWeeks.map(w => $("<td>")))
            );
        const types = users[u];
        return r.concat(Object.keys(types).sort().map(t => $("<tr>")
            .append($("<td>").text(t))
            .append($("<td>").text(Object.keys(types[t])
                .reduce((y, m) => y + Object.keys(types[t][m] || {})
                    .reduce((y, w) => y + types[t][m][w], 0), 0)))
            .append(weeksByMonth
                .reduce((w, m) => {
                    const month = types[t][m.month] || {};
                    return w.concat(m.weeks.map(w => month["Week" + w] || 0)
                        .concat(Object.keys(month).reduce((t, w) => t + month[w], 0)));
                }, [])
                .map(t => $("<td>").text(t))
            )
        ));
    }, [])
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-diffie-ep56w

Comment: Is it possible to add yearly total column after username and before week1

Comment: please help me to add 0 in empty week cell

Comment: @user3386779 updated to fill 0. you should try yearly yourself.

Comment: @user3386779 Can't you learn from the monthly total code?

Comment: @user3386779 although without more reputations, I added yearly anyway.

Comment: @user3386779 Yes.

Comment: Tried to add geo as https://jsfiddle.net/zxg1p4Lf/1/ commented code in that fiddle

Comment: Please help me to add geo

Comment: Any material to gain knowledge in reduce,map usage

Comment: Do not ask a new question in comments. Ask a new question as a question.

Comment: sure will post a new question